# Find in nested records in mongoDB (nested by reference ObjectId)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

I have two records , order and user , and my order has an object id of its user this is my records :

order :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56ea382b3c21a4a74591dc99"),
  "user" : ObjectId("56ea382b3c21a4a74591dc98"),
  "created" : 1458190379858
}
```

and user :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56febb7b4597977168894445"),
  "phone" : "09197377057",
  "created" : 1459170746688,
}
```

How can I find orders which their user's phone is for example "09197377057"

Is it possible in mongodb or mongoose to find something like this ?

Comment: I want to access the data in a single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)*** is what you need here if you want in a single query.

```
db.order.aggregate({
    $lookup: {
        from: "user",
        localField: "user",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "order_user"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "order_user.phone": "09197377057"
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Can I apply aggregate and populate at the same time ?

Comment: I'm entirely sure as to how mongoose works but I think you'll have to aggregate first and then populate the results. The above example does both the lookup and aggregate on the server side.